# Service Console Component at the top instead of the footer

Tags: custom, console, search, service

I have implemented a customized external search component for the Service Console and I added this VisualForce page to the console using the **Choose Console Components** from the Console itself in Create Apps from Setup.

The thing is that in doing so the custom component shows at the bottom of the console page in the footer section: when the button is clicked the search bar shows up:

[image: Custom Search Button in the footer section]

I am looking for a way to move this component at the top of the console. Being this Custom Search visualforce page I created a generic one, i.e. not a controller to a specific object the page, it doesn't show up in the VisualForce pages that can be added within the Case Layout, for example,also cause the bar is needed for multiple objects. So, ideally, the place where I would want this bar is at the top, right below the Search Salesforce bar section, right before the Case Layout starts.

Do you think this is possible?

Thanks a lot for the attention!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that option you are looking for is not supported in Console.

Though you are trying to search based on email address or phone and that can be applicable across multiple objects, I would recommend you to use Global Search functionality. In the global search results you can pin the list which user wants to see first in the order.

If you are trying to do in a custom way, you cannot meet the performance of Global search which Salesforce provides and ultimately, user will end up using Global Search instead of your custom search functionality.